# How to reposition Widgets from BoxLayout

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm using latest version of kivy: `v1.10.1.dev0, git-Unknown, 20171208`, python `v3.6.2`, mac os.

I want to achive the following: when I update a value in settings reposition/redraw `BoxLayout` with the changed settings, in my case I'm updating `size_hint` value. Here is the work I have so far:

my.py

```
from kivy.app import App


class MyApp(App):
    def build_config(self, config):
        config.read('./my.ini')

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Test', self.config, filename='my.json')

    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        if section in ('layout',) and key in ('size_hint',):
            # NOT WORKING!!
            # print(self.root.canvas.clear())
            # self.root.canvas.ask_update()
            # self.root.canvas.draw()

            # NOT WORKING!!
            print(self.root)
            print(self.root.do_layout())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv

```
#:import SettingsWithSidebar kivy.uix.settings.SettingsWithSidebar
BoxLayout:
    RecycleView:
        size_hint: float(app.config.get('layout', 'size_hint')), 1
        Button:
            text: 'Open Settings'
            on_touch_down: app.settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar; app.open_settings()
    RecycleView:
        size_hint: 1-float(app.config.get('layout', 'size_hint')), 1
        Button:
            text: 'Just a test'
```

my.ini

```
[layout]
size_hint = 0.6
```

my.json

```
[
  {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Size Hint",
        "desc": "Size Hint",
        "section": "layout",
        "key": "size_hint"
    }
]
```

So, how do I see the new layout updated with new value of `size_hint` when I close the settings window?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some help from IRC #Kivy the solution is to not use directly `app.config.get('layout', 'size_hint')` in `.kv` file but used `Properties` instead.

my.kv

```
BoxLayout:
    RecycleView:
        size_hint: app.size_hint, 1
        Button:
            text: 'Open Settings'
            on_touch_down: app.open_settings()
    RecycleView:
        size_hint: 1-app.size_hint, 1
        Button:
            text: 'Just a test'
```

my.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSidebar


class MyApp(App):
    settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar
    size_hint = NumericProperty()

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.read('./my.ini')

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Test', self.config, filename='my.json')

    def load_config(self):
        config = super(MyApp, self).load_config()
        self.size_hint = config.getfloat('layout', 'size_hint')
        return config

    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        if section in ('layout',) and key in ('size_hint',):
            self.size_hint = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```